Как добавить в apk несколько одинаковых библиотек (jar) для разных устройств?
Цель: сделать одну apk, которая бы работала с разными устройствами через одно апи, которое различается реализацией внутри этого апи.
Есть ряд устройств, их разработчик предоставляет для каждого свое апи в виде файла api.jar.
Апи примерно одинаковое для всех устройств. Для каждого устройства методы, переменные и т.д., внутри этого api.jar они одинаковые, но реализация и значения могут быть разные. (Интерфейс один, реализация может отличаться) Каких то методов и констант может не быть вообще. Внутри у всех api.jar пути и названия методов, констант  и т.д. совпадают, если они есть.
Задача: как это всё можно собрать в одну апк, и в рантайме, в зависимости от модели устройства, переключаться на разное апи (т.е. использовать апи из какого то конкретного jar-файла)?
Как искать это в гугле? По каким ключевым словам?  Это ж не модули.
Вариант сборки типа "один апк под одно апи" не вариант.
Это всё для Андроид 4.2.2, гугл маркета нет и не будет. Есть вариант переписывания на Котлин, если это решит проблему, хотя я хз как оно решит

Если они "одинаковые" то оставьте одну.
